# Check if name exists in object array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object array that looks just about like this

```
 var o = [
   {
    module : "mod1",
    customUrl : [
        { "state"    : "name1",
          "options"  : ["option1", "option2", "option3"]
        },
        { "state"    : "name2",
          "options"  : ["option1", "option2", "option3"]
        }
    ]
  },
 {
    module : "mod2",
    customUrl : [
        { "state"    : "name1",
          "options"  : ["option1", "option2", "option3"]
        },
        { "state"    : "name2",
          "options"  : ["option1", "option2", "option3"]
        }
    ]
 }
]
```

and in a function I a passed a string. I want to be able to check that string against the "module" keys and see if it matches any of them so like

```
 checkName = function(name) {
      //check if "name" matches any "module" in o

 }
```

Is this possible (I am using underscore but normal javascript is fine too).Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function [some](http://underscorejs.org/#some), like so

```
var checkName = function(name) {
  return _.some(o, function (el) {
    return el.module === name;
  });
};
```

or [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) from `Array`

```
var checkName = function(name) {
  return o.some(function (el) {
    return el.module === name;
  });
};
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/zedogu/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

Pure Javascript solution. This function returns false if the module name is not found or the position in the array when the name is found. This function does not count in duplicates, it only will give the position from the last match.

[JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/zvxp8ddg/)

```
var checkName = function(name) {
    var flag=false;
    for(var i=0; i<o.length;i++){
        if(name === o[i].module){
            flag=i;
        }
    }return flag;
};
console.log(checkName("mod2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite another way to do so wiit pure, native JavaScript: convert the object to string and check for exact module-part.

```js
var checkName = function(haystack, needle) {
  return JSON.stringify(haystack).contains('"module":"' + needle + '"')
}

checkName(o, 'mod1'); // returns true
checkName(o, 'mod4'); // returns false
```